# Список не входит в div

Tags: html, css, список

сделал логотип и список внутри одного дива, но список переносится на следующую строку.
[image: Скриншот страницы]

Вот исходники:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>China Season</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 980px) and (mix-width: 600px)" href="responsive.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
          <div id="shapka">
             <div id="logo">
              <a class="logo" href="index.html" name="Логотип">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
                </a>
              </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Как мы работаем</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Преимущества</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
</style>

#page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: center;
    position: relative;
}

#shapka {
    height: 150px;
}

#logo {
    width: 300px;
}

#logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: center;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: center;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-бы список не сместился вправа добавьте тегу `ul` следующий стили

```
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
#page {
    width: 960px;
    margin: center;
    position: relative;
}

#shapka {
    height: 150px;
}

#logo {
    width: 300px;
}

#logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: center;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>China Season</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 980px) and (mix-width: 600px)" href="responsive.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
          <div id="shapka">
             <div id="logo">
              <a class="logo" href="index.html" name="Логотип">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
                </a>
              </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Как мы работаем</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Преимущества</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```